# %bquote doesn't mask unpaired bracket

Tags: sas, sas-macro

According %bquote() macro function documentation I don't have to mark unpaired "(" with % to assign it to macro variable.

But this code doesn't work for some reason (variable var is blank as a result):

```
%let var=%bquote(();
%put &var;
```

Why? How can I fix code to produce expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing masking at *execution time* with masking at *compile time*.

`%BQUOTE` masks special characters [at execution time](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/69726/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0frhtfqvguv78n1owh5wfeopdrj.htm):

> The %BQUOTE function treats all parentheses and quotation marks produced by resolving macro variable references or macro calls as special characters to be masked at execution time. (It does not mask parentheses or quotation marks that are in the argument at compile time.)

To mask it at *compile* time, which you must since you are assigning its value in a `%let`, you must use `%str`, which *does* require a parenthesis to be preceded by a `%`.

```
%let var=%str(%();

%put &var;
```